# Utilizar ruta dinámica desde db para generar un bg en tailwind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind

hola estoy creando un sitio en next.js 13 y tailwind y  quiero generar un bg con una ruta dinamica que llega de la database, pero me da este error :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui el codigo:

```
const BlogCard = async ({ categoryId }) => {
const blog = await fetchBlog(categoryId);

return (
    <div className={`bg-[url("${blog.image_url}")]`}>
        <a
            href="#"
            class="flex flex-col items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow md:flex-row md:max-w-xl hover:bg-gray-100 dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-700"
        >
            <Image
                class="object-cover w-full rounded-t-lg h-full  md:h-auto md:w-48 md:rounded-none md:rounded-l-lg"
                src={blog.image_url}
                height={600}
                width={200}
                alt={blog.alt}
            />
            <div class="flex flex-col justify-between p-4 leading-normal">
                <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                    Noteworthy technology acquisitions 2021
                </h5>
                <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
                    Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions
                    of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.
                </p>
            </div>
        </a>

        {/* soy blog card
        {blog ? (
            <div className='flex'>
                <Image
                    src={blog.image_url}
                    height={400}
                    width={400}
                    alt={blog.alt}
                ></Image>
                <h1>{blog.title}</h1>
                <p>{blog.description}</p>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div> error al cargar datos</div>
        )} */}
    </div>
);
```

};
el problema es aqui en div padre, donde utilizo backstics para introducir el valor de la url que viene desde la db, eso esta funcionando ya q en el  funciona bien

```
  <div className={`bg-[url("${blog.image_url}")]`}>
```

ya que si lo quito, funciona correctamente